# Catched Image Widget : Failed assertion Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Sometimes when I start the app, I get this issue

'package:cached_network_image/src/cached_image_widget.dart': Failed assertion: line 157 pos 16: 'imageUrl != null': is not true.

In the cached_image_widget.dart at line 157 :

```
 : assert(imageUrl != null),
```

And In the file when I call the cached image widget :

```
child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: itemArticle.urlToImage,
                      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
                        return Container(
                          width: 72.0,
                          height: 72.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: imageProvider,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
```

My app show a card view (list).

What do you think about it? Some how we can resolve it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a null check to it. That's because you are providing a `null` value to your `CachedNetworkImage`.

Basically, an easy fix:

```
child: itemArticle.urlToImage != null ?
    CachedNetworkImage(...) : Container() // Or some other widget.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default image using `itemArticle.urlToImage ?? defaultImageUrl`

```
child: CachedNetworkImage(
   imageUrl: itemArticle.urlToImage ?? defaultImageUrl,
   imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
       return Container(
           width: 72.0,
           height: 72.0,
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
               image: DecorationImage(
                   image: imageProvider,
                   fit: BoxFit.cover,
               ),
           ),
        );
    },
```